# How to write a controller that sends an array as a URL parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, parameter-passing

In some MVC platforms, a controller method accepts an URL's contents as forward-slash separated list of elements, received as parameters, e.g.

```
 site.com/controller/method/var1/var2
```

has associated controller:

```
class Controller

  function method(var1, var2){
  }
}
```

But how can I achieve this coding? I wish to start with an array and send a parameterized list to a function, i.e.

```
$args = array("one"=>"cheese","two"=>"eggs");

php_function("myfunction",$args);
```

Within `myfunction`, I would have

```
function myfunction($one, $two){
}
```

I know about `func_get_args` for accepting an unknown number of arguments. `user_call_func` is useful except

```
user_call_func("myfunction",$args);
```

...results in the first parameter containing an array of arguments, no difference to `func_get_args` called from within the function.

`extract` doesn't work either as I need to receive the array as a variable inside the function.

Comment: Are you asking how to arrange the URL, or how to read it? For the former, I expect `site.com/controller/myfunction/cheese,eggs` will do it. If you are intending to write your own routing system, I advise you not to bother - there are plenty out there at the moment, and there's no value in reinventing the wheel. The Slim framework one is quite good, and I expect Zend and Symfony have their own modules you can use separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to create your desired with the following.

```
class BootStrap {

private $controller = 'NameOfIle.php';
private $method = 'function()';
private $params = array('sdfds' => 'dsfdsf', 'sdfdsfsdfdsfsd' => 'sdfdsfds');


public function __construct() {
  call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, $this->method), $this->params);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) takes a method description and an array of arguments, and returns the result of calling the function. I think it will take the arguments from the array in order though, rather than by name. You should assemble an array of the arguments in the correct order, and perhaps validate for missing arguments, before using this.

Comment: thanks. it's correct but Matthew A has shown a full example so I've green-ticked him.